# Are there any security concerns with running two daemons on the same host, with one for remote purposes?

Tags: monerod, remote-access

I'm running a regular node on a VPS (interacts with rpc wallet via PHP), and would like to use the same VPS as a remote node for my GUI wallet. Are there any security concerns if I do this? These are the two commands I'd use for the daemons:

For the regular node:

`./monerod --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-port 18081`

The second instance I'd use to connect to from an external GUI wallet:

`./monerod --rpc-bind-ip <external.ip.of.node> --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind`

Finally, in the second instance, is there any security risk to using `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0` instead of `--rpc-bind-ip <external.ip.of.node>`?

Comment: It mainly depends on your threat model. Generally there's no high risk to have one instance of monerod and at the same time monero-wallet-rpc. At the same time, if any critical issues (e.g. RCE) are discovered, your machine will be put at risk. Try to figure out what a malicious actor can do once entered in your VPS.